# How does (!class || case2){} work in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to understand this code, particularly, the 3rd line:

[image]

I came across this answer on this site:

[image]

The whole code is here:

[image]
[image]

How is whether `!name` = true or not determined here? I'm just trying to understand, otherwise I can just memorise it

Comment: Please put the relevant code directly into the question and not through images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
if (!name || name.length > 20)
```

where `name` is a string, will first check `!name`. The only string which is falsey is the empty string, so `!name` will only be fulfilled if `name` is the empty string: `dog.name = ''` will call the setter and fulfill `!name`, and so the `if` block will run, throwing an error.

```
if (!name || name.length < 20)
// where name is the empty string:
if (!'' || name.length < 20)
if (true || name.length < 20)
if (true)
```

Otherwise, the `name` is not the empty string, so `name.length` gets tested. If the length is `< 20`, the whole condition evaluates to `true`, otherwise it evaluates to `false`.

So, the whole `name` setter does: if the parameter is an empty string, or if the parameter's string is 20 characters or longer, an error will be thrown. Otherwise, the `_name` property of the instance is set to the parameter.

Comment: Thanks! Understood all of it except (might be a silly question)...but what doesn `!` mean here?

Comment: `!` inverts the truthyness of an expression. A truthy value will turn into `false`. A falsey value will turn into `true`.

Comment: Here is a useful resource to know what is truthy and falsy in js / ts (green is truthy, white is falsy): https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/#if-statement